# Pascal's Triangle fails past row 14

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that outputs Pascal's triangle for a computer science class, and everything is correct on the output until it gets past row 14, wherein it starts outputting odd irrational numbers. Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>

#include "myFunctions.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {
  int rows;
  cout << "Please Enter The Number of Rows: ";
  cin >> rows;
  cout << rows << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < (rows - i + 1); j++) {
      cout << " ";
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
      if (k == 0) {
        cout << "1" << " ";
      } else {
        cout << combination(i, k) << " ";
      }
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And here's my functions file:

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_CPP_INCLUDED
#define MYFUNCTIONS_CPP_INCLUDED

#include "myFunctions.h"


double factorial (int n) {
  assert(n >= 0);

  int v = 1;
  while (n > 0) {
    v *= n;
    n--;
  }
  return v;
}

double combination (int a, int b) {

  return (factorial(a) / (factorial(a - b) * factorial(b)));
}


#endif // MYFUNCTIONS_CPP_INCLUDED
```

And, finally, here's my header file.

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>


//*******************************************************
// description: finds factorial of value                *
// return: double                                       *
// precondition: that the value is valid and an integer *
// postcondition: returns the factorial of value        *
//*******************************************************
double factorial( int n );


//********************************************************
// description: finds combination of value               *
// return: double                                        *
// precondition: both values are integers and valid      *
// postcondition: returns the  combination of two values *
//********************************************************
double combination( int a, int b );



#endif // MYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

I'm assuming that I did the equations within functions incorrect, or something specific is happening in main once it hits 14. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry for pedantry, but it is certainly not printing "irrational numbers". Please include expected and actual output in the question

Comment: Don't use floating point (double) for integer problems.

Comment: if `factorial` returns a `double`, why do all the multiplications in `int`? That'll overflow.

Comment: Can you calculate (by hand) what `factorial(14)` is and what it should be? Remember that in c++, `int`s have a maximum value of 2147483647 while 14!=87178291200. Its likely that, like Johnny Mopp says, you've got overflow

Comment: factorial is always suspectible to overflows. Do the maths first. Try to find a way to calculate `(factorial(a) / (factorial(a - b) * factorial(b)))` that does not involve calculating denominator and numerator fully, most of it cancels out anyhow

Comment: `combination` can be done by cancelling out the terms above and below to avoid working out 2 factorials.

Comment: @JakobLovern "_in c++, `int`s have a maximum value of 2147483647_" - "have" is too strong. `int`s may have a maximum of 32767 or 2147483647 or 9223372036854775807 ... or some future value, like 170141183460469231731687303715884105727 for 128 bit `int`s. To my knowledge `int`s only have a lower limit (16 bits).

Comment: Fair enough. Guess I assumed without thinking there.

Comment: If you need to output the Pascal's Triangle, it is more efficient to calculate all lines iteratively, i.e. `C(n,k) = C(n-1,k) + C(n-1, k-1)`

Answer (score 2):

### What's going on

`int`s in C++ have a maximum size. As mentioned in comments, depends on your platform but for the sake of this question, I'll assume it's `2^31-1` which corresponds to a 32-bit signed integer and is what I most commonly see.

The issue comes in when you get to factorials. They grow *very* quickly. 14!=87178291200 which is a whole lot bigger than the maximum size of a 32 bit `int`. There's no feasible way to keep the whole factorial in memory for an arbitrary n! because of how large they can get.

It's not that your code is broken, it's simply running up against the physical bounds of computing.

### How can we fix it?

First off, you could cancel out factorials. Basically, since we can guarantee that a>=b, we know that a!/b! is just multiplying the numbers between a and b. We can do that with a loop. Then it's just a matter of dividing by (a-b)!, which we already know how to do. This would look like

```cpp
int combination(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = 1;
    for(int ii = b;ii<=a;ii++)
        tmp*=ii;
    tmp /= factorial(b);
    return tmp;
}
```

More efficiently, we can switch to a different algorithm. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) recommends using an iterative method for pascal's triangle. That is, each element can be calculated from two elements in the row above it. As @Damien mentions in comments, if you're looking for the kth element in row n, then you can calculate that by

```cpp
int Combination(int n,int k)
{
    if (k == 0 or k>n or n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return Combination(n-1,k) + Combination(n-1,k-1);
}
```

Comment: *"size of int depends on your computer"* is a bit misleading. If you transfer a compiled program to a different computer, the size will remain the same.

Comment: The width of an integer is whatever your compiler feels like setting it to based on the environment you're (cross-)compiling for. I feel like the whole point of int width is ancillary to the topic at hand and liable to confuse.

Comment: If there were a concise way to mention that 14! > `INT_MAX` without going into the minutia of widths of builtin types, I would absolutely prefer that.

Comment: *"depends on your platform"* is one way to word it.